# Why angular 1.2.9 DOM callback is fired immediately?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

#### Demo http://jsbin.com/utOrAPO/1/edit?html,js,output

#### Source https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dde1b2949727c297e214c99960141bfad438d7a4#diff-fc9e96da9f5a9dfda43ef79e695d27ccR853

Angular 1.2.9 introduced DOM callback. `$animate:before` and `$animate:after` event will be triggered on animated element when performing animations. However, `$animate:after` is triggered immediately after `$animate:before` event instead of after animation is finished.

There is no difference whether I'm using CSS or JS animation. (http://jsbin.com/utOrAPO/3/edit)

**My question is: Is it intended for DOM callback to be like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/ca6b7d0fa2e355ebd764230260758cee9a4ebe1e , Angular 1.2.10 has added a new event `$animate:close` to trigger when animation completed.